# why linux rpath only take affect on some library

Tags: linux, linker

I link my program with -Wl,-rpath=./
but it failed to search the library. the debug shows run path only take affect on some library. log:

```
find library=libepsverifier.so [0]; searching
search path=./tls/x86_64/x86_64:./tls/x86_64:./tls/x86_64:./tls:./x86_64/x86_64:./x86_64:./x86_64:.     (RUNPATH from file ./sim)
trying file=./tls/x86_64/x86_64/libepsverifier.so
 trying file=./tls/x86_64/libepsverifier.so
trying file=./libepsverifier.so


find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
search path=./tls/x86_64/x86_64:./tls/x86_64:./tls/x86_64:./tls:./x86_64/x86_64:./x86_64:./x86_64:.     (RUNPATH from file ./sim)
trying file=./tls/x86_64/x86_64/libc.so.6
...
trying file=./x86_64/libc.so.6
trying file=./libc.so.6
search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

find library=libepsbase.so [0]; searching
search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls/x86_64:/lib/tls:/lib/x86_64/x86_64:/lib/x86_64:/lib/x86_64:/lib:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/usr/lib/tls:/usr/lib/x86_64/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib/x86_64:/usr/lib     (system search path)
trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libeps
。。。
trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libepsbase.so
trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64/libepsbase.so
trying file=/usr/lib/libepsbase.so
./sim: error while loading shared libraries: libepsbase.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

why libepsverifier is searched in .
but linker don't search libepsbase under .

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure on what you want to achieve, honestly I never tried rpath in the way you are trying to use it. Am I right if your expect the compiler to scan the entire file system for it? This is not what it is meant for.

Probably the other libraries are found because they are referenced in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH of your environment or because they are in locations recognized by your environment as "the place where libraries are".

The sequence should be

1. DT_RPATH section of the executable
2. LD_LIBRARY_PATH
3. DT_RUNPATH section of the executable
4. /etc/ld/so/cache
5. default directories /lib then /usr/lib

To have a proper test, either include the path of the library in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or pass the rpath with a full path of the library. If it works, this is the reason why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same `-Wl,-rpath=/some/path` option when compiling a shared library if you want that path to be also used when searching the shared libraries that library itself depends upon.

Example:

```
$ echo 'void bar(){printf("bar\n");}' > bar.c
$ echo 'extern void bar(); void foo(){bar();}' > foo.c
$ echo 'extern void foo(); int main(){foo();}' > main.c

$ mkdir -p dir
$ cc bar.c -shared -o dir/libbar.so -include stdio.h
$ cc foo.c -Ldir -lbar -shared -o dir/libfoo.so
$ cc main.c -Ldir -lfoo -o main -Wl,-rpath=./dir
$ ./main
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ cc foo.c -Ldir -lbar -shared -o dir/libfoo.so -Wl,-rpath=./dir
                                               #^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$ ./main
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the "`search path=./tls/x86_64/x86_64:./tls/x86_64:./tls/x86_64:./tls:./x86_64/x86_64:./x86_64:./x86_64:.     (RUNPATH from file ./sim)`" in line 2 of the output in the OP. I'd like to know where it comes from. It's not `RPATH`, not `RUNPATH`, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and also not a combination of `$ORIGIN, $LIB` and `$PLATFORM`. It's also not the linker script which you can verify using `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR`. Finally, it's not in the `/etc/ld.so.conf` or any of the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`.

So where does it come from?

And no, it seems not to be in the library code in `dlopen()`. I looked it up in the GNU C Library and it's straight forward, just a call to a static function.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not a question.